# How to get both drive predicates working in prolog?

Tags: prolog, win-prolog

```
begin:- 

go,
initialise.             % drive predicate

begin:-
write('Sorry cannot help'),nl,nl.



go:-
write('Below is the list of the current toys available within the 

store.'),nl,nl,nl,nl,
loop_through_list([car, football, action_men, train_tracks, lego, football, bikes, control_car, drees_up, doll, bear, furbies, craft, doll_house]).
loop_through_list([Head|Tail]) :-
    write(Head),
    write(' '),
    loop_through_list(Tail).
initialise:-
nl,nl,nl,nl,
tab(40),write('******************************************'),nl,
tab(40),write('*** TOY GENERATING SYSTEM ***'),nl,
tab(40),write('******************************************'),nl,nl,
write('Please answer the following questions'),
write(' y (yes) or n (no).'),nl,nl, nl, nl.
```

The problem here is that the `go:-` and the `initialise:-` work separately when on their own, but not when put together. Is there a problem with all the `nl`s?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a colon after 'initialise'? ie begin:- go, initialise.

Comment: yes sorry. forgot to put that in, this is only part of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `go/0` doesn't work corrently. While it prints the list, it fails at the end, meaning that the execution will stop afterwards. Therefore, when you run `begin/0`, `initialize/0` will never run.

To fix it you need to add a base case for `loop_through_list/0`:

```
loop_through_list([]).
loop_through_list([Head|Tail]) :-
    write(Head),
    write(' '),
    loop_through_list(Tail).
```

As a side note, "print_list" would be a more descriptive name for `loop_through_list/0`

Comment: @W_K you're welcome; btw you can also use `writef/2` [http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=writef/2] for io: `writef("%w  ", [Head])`

Comment: @thanosQR: format/2 is the more common name for this. Do you see a reason, why there is `writef/2` at all?